# Авто-добавление двоеточия в поле формы

Tags: jquery

Имеется поле формы:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="duration" maxlength="8" value="00:">
</form>
```

Как заставить jQuery вписывать после каждых двух цифр двоеточие? т.е. автоматически формировать время:
ввожу `002517`, получаю `00:25:17`

Comment: отслеживать событие инпута и редактировать ввод так как нужно

Comment: Можно использовать https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput  .... примеры использования: http://www.xiper.net/examples/js-plugins/interface/masked-input/masked-input.html

Comment: @Алексей, отлично, это оно.